# Missing methods trying to create a criteria

Tags: grails, grails-orm, createcriteria

My Employee domain has an associated division, department, and position, which are all domains themselves. This relationship is coded as

```
class Employee
{
    ...
    String firstName
    String lastName
    Position position
    Division division
    Department department
    ...
}
```

(note that there is no `belongsTo` or `hasOne` relationship) I send in the id of each of these selected from a drop-down list with

```
<g:select name="department" from="${Department.list()}" optionKey="id" optionValue="${{it.name}}" />
```

(similarly for division and position), but I am getting an error with the code querying the database

```
def employeeList = Employee.createCriteria().list(sort: params.sort, order: params.order) 
{
    and 
    {
        ilike "firstName", "%${params.firstName}%" 
        ilike "lastName", "%${params.lastName}%"
    }
    position
    {
        eq "position", ${params.position}
    }
    department
    {
        eq "department", ${params.department}
    }
    division
    {
        eq "division", ${params.division}
    }
}
```

The error I get is

```
No signature of method: EmployeeController.department() is applicable for argument types: (EmployeeController$_results_closure1_closure4) values: [EmployeeController$_results_closure1_closure4@f559db0]
```

I've tried putting in the division/department/position `eq` snippets inside the and block, but that fails with the error

```
No signature of method: EmployeeController.and() is applicable for argument types: (EmployeeController$_results_closure1_closure4) values: [EmployeeController$_results_closure1_closure4@2f3302f3]
```

Any ideas what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

You need to start your criteria closure on the same line as the `.list()` call. The closure is supposed to be an argument to the `list()` method but when it starts on the next line Groovy is executing `list()` and then trying to create a closure.

```
def employeeList = Employee.createCriteria().list(sort: params.sort, order: params.order) {
    and {
        ilike "firstName", "%${params.firstName}%" 
        ilike "lastName", "%${params.lastName}%"
    }
    position {
        eq "position", params.position
    }
    department {
        eq "department", params.department
    }
    division {
        eq "division", params.division
    }
}
```

This is equivalent to below (note the parenthesis)

```
def employeeList = Employee.createCriteria().list([sort: params.sort, order: params.order], {
    and {
        ilike "firstName", "%${params.firstName}%" 
        ilike "lastName", "%${params.lastName}%"
    }
    position {
        eq "position", params.position
    }
    department {
        eq "department", params.department
    }
    division {
        eq "division", params.division
    }
})
```

Also note that you were using GString syntax without the requisite `"` in your `eq` criteria.